Space is a retract of mapping cylinder
I'm trying to show that $X$ is a retract of mapping cylinder $M_f$ if and only if $f$ has a left homotopy inverse (this is a map $g:Y\rightarrow X$ such that $g\circ f\simeq \text{id}_X$).
I've managed to show that if $f$ has a left homotopy inverse then $X$ is a retract of $M_f$. But how to prove the fact in the opposite direction?
Let $r:M_f \rightarrow X$ be a retraction. It seems that one should take $g: Y\rightarrow X$, $g(y) = r(y)$. However, I don't understand how to show that $g\circ f\simeq \text{id}_X$.

Hint : How are $X$ and $Y$ included in $M_f$? What happens when you look at $g(f(x))$ via the mapping cylinder identifications?

Recall that $M_f = (X\times [0,1]\amalg Y)/\sim$, where the equivalence relation is given by $(x,1)\sim f(x)$. Denote by $i_X\colon X\to M_f, i_X(x) = [(x,0)]$ and $i_Y\colon Y\to M_f$ the inclusions into the mapping cylinder. Then $i_X$ is homotopic to $i_Y\circ f$ via the homotopy $h(x,t) = [(x,t)]$, hence $r\circ i_Y\circ f$ is homotopic to $r\circ i_X = \mathrm{id}_X$. Thus, $g= r\circ i_Y$ is the desired left homotopy inverse of $f$.

I'm new to algebraic topology, so it is not clear to me why $i_X$ is homotopic to $i_Y\circ f$. Could you please explain how to build a homotopy?

@GeoArt Is it clear now?

Yes, thanks a lot!
